# What happened to an ETH transaction that shows up pending for a period of time and then disappears?

Tags: transactions

I sent ETH to an address and it showed pending for a period of time on etherscan and then disappears. Is it dead or canceled or lost or what? If I send a duplicate transaction what happens to the first one?

Comment: it is not a question of "if" , you WILL have to send another transaction with a higher gas price (and same nonce) to overwrite previous (stuck) transaction. Because Etherscan is not the only node on the network, your transaction is now stored as pending on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

below is what happened to me:

Sent a transaction and it went pending, it was keep showing and not showing (meaning it's inside the pool but no miner picks it up and no block is assigned; low gas price and too many transaction in the pool recently was the reason), after 12 hrs it went through (paid $1.5 gas price).

I performed another transaction ($0.35 gas), it did not fail but not shown after couple of hrs and never went through so i did another trans (after 1.5 days). I know how frustrating this could be but I suggest to wait for 2 days to see if it goes through and then send another. Hope it helps :) let me know if you still face the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since your transactions gas price is too low to even be assigned to a block etherscan just losses track of it because it is not even assigned to a block.
its still there though. even if its still pending